# how to get frequency of a variable for each row in a dataframe(table changes the length of dataframe though)

Tags: r

Example

```
x<- c("a","a","b","c","c","c","d")
```

I like frequencies to be:

```
> a a b c c c d
> 2 2 1 3 3 3 1
```

and not

```
> a b c d
> 2 1 3 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `table` as a named vector

```
table(x)[x]
x
# a a b c c c d  
# 2 2 1 3 3 3 1
```

---

or with `ave`

```
setNames(ave(seq_along(x), x, FUN = length), x)
#a a b c c c d 
#2 2 1 3 3 3 1
```

Comment: I'm surprised that you also got a downvote as your solution with `table()` should work universally.

Comment: It's disturbing. I think a working solution should not be downvoted. Or at least not without mentioning what is the problem with the post. Anyway, this post of yours is really nice (already upvoted it). Just wanted to say it.

Comment: @tmfmnk@akrun Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `rle()`:

```
with(rle(x), setNames(rep(lengths, lengths), rep(values, lengths)))

a a b c c c d 
2 2 1 3 3 3 1
```

However, it assumes one run per group (as indicated by letters). Additionally, it could also work properly if you have several runs per group, but the vector could be sorted:

```
x <- c("a","b","c","c","c","d","a")

with(rle(sort(x)), setNames(rep(lengths, lengths), rep(values, lengths)))

a a b c c c d 
2 2 1 3 3 3 1
```

If there are several runs per group and the vector could not be sorted, then this solution is not feasible.